# Using lmfit model to best fit the multiple peaks data

Tags: python, lmfit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
x=np.array([4698.031, 4698.027, 4698.024, 4698.021, 4698.017, 4698.014,4698.011, 4698.007, 4698.004, 4698.001, 4697.997, 4697.994, 4697.991, 4697.987, 4697.984, 4697.981, 4697.977, 4697.974, 4697.971, 4697.967, 4697.964, 4697.961, 4697.957, 4697.954, 4697.951, 4697.947, 4697.944, 4697.941, 4697.937, 4697.934, 4697.931, 4697.927, 4697.924, 4697.921, 4697.917])
y=np.array([0.56565, 0.586575, 0.70335, 0.991245, 1.447545, 4.944375, 11.97281, 18.22095, 19.7613, 17.13792, 13.35083, 10.26506, 7.898505, 5.084775, 2.4192, 1.34358, 0.829905, 1.31322, 3.2049, 4.0095, 2.83263, 1.51605, 0.643275, 0.48972, 0.432675, 0.084375, 0.135345, 0.362145, 0.34425, 0.307125, 0.469125, 0.297, 0.183255, 0.528855, 0.523125])
gmodel = Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_')
params = gmodel.make_params(p1_amp=0.1, p1_cen=4697.97, p1_wid=0.005, p2_amp=0.5, p2_cen=4698.00, p2_wid=0.005)


params['p1_cen'].min = x.min()
params['p1_cen'].max = 4697.98
params['p2_cen'].min = 4697.98
params['p2_cen'].max = x.max()

result = gmodel.fit(y, params, x=x)
```

**updated program**
few questions

1. When I run the program it gives me an error.
   Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 7, in 
    gmodel = Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_')

NameError: name 'gaussian' is not defined

For which i include `from lmfit.lineshapes import gaussian`and it works.

Is is right or wrong??

2. After adding the library/package the program says
   Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 9, in 
    params['p1_'].min = x.min()

KeyError: 'p1_cen'

help me with this.

3. After removing the `params` the program runs without any errors but what do i do in order to show plots for my *given data* n the *best fit data* . I just did `plt.plot(x,y)` for my given data but no idea what to do for my best fit data.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give better starting guesses.  Your data `x` ranges from 4697.8 to 4698.0, but your initial guess for `cen` is 1.0, way outside your data range.  Change the initial values to more sensible values for your data.

**Update to address the question of how to fit 2 peaks:**

To fit 2 peaks, you can create a composite model, as with

```py
gmodel = Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_')

result  = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, p1_amp=0.1, p1_cen=4697.97, p1_wid=0.005,
                     p2_amp=0.5, p2_cen=4698.00, p2_wid=0.005)
```

This will create a model that has 2 Gaussians added together, and giving the parameter names for one model a prefix `p1_` and the parameters for the other a prefix of `p2_`.  You can then give initial values for each of these when doing the fit.

It is generally recommended to create an instance of `lmfit.Parameters` for each model, as this allows you to further manipulate the parameter settings, for example, to set upper and lower bounds.  For this kind of model, it might be helpful to make sure the peaks cannot overlap too closely or overlap.  You could do that like this:

```py
gmodel = Model(gaussian, prefix='p1_') + Model(gaussian, prefix='p2_')

params = gmodel.make_params(p1_amp=0.1, p1_cen=4697.97, p1_wid=0.005,
                            p2_amp=0.5, p2_cen=4698.00, p2_wid=0.005)
params['p1_cen'].min = x.min()
params['p1_cen'].max = 4697.98
params['p2_cen'].min = 4697.98
params['p2_cen'].max = x.max()

result = gmodel.fit(y, params, x=x)
```

which sets `min`/`max` values for the `cen` parameters for each model so that they cannot swap.

Comment: but now the problem is that this program is not fitting the multiple peaks that i have in my given data ...which is 
x=np.array([4698.031,
4698.027,
4698.024,
4698.021,
4698.017,
4698.014,
4698.011,
4698.007,
4698.004,
4698.001,
4697.997,
4697.994,
4697.991,
4697.987,
4697.984,
4697.981,
4697.977,
4697.974,
4697.971,
4697.967,
4697.964,
4697.961,
4697.957,
4697.954,
4697.951,
4697.947,
4697.944,
4697.941,
4697.937,
4697.934,
4697.931,
4697.927,
4697.924,
4697.921,
4697.917])

Comment: y=np.array([0.56565,
0.586575,
0.70335,
0.991245,
1.447545,
4.944375,
11.97281,
18.22095,
19.7613,
17.13792,
13.35083,
10.26506,
7.898505,
5.084775,
2.4192,
1.34358,
0.829905,
1.31322,
3.2049,
4.0095,
2.83263,
1.51605,
0.643275,
0.48972,
0.432675,
0.084375,
0.135345,
0.362145,
0.34425,
0.307125,
0.469125,
0.297,
0.183255,
0.528855,
0.523125])

Comment: Please update your question with the new(?) data.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "overlap the data exactly" - do you mean "make the fit better"?  For data with multiple peaks, you'll need to update your model to include multiple peaks.  lmfit Models make this easy, as you can add Models together....

Comment: yes make the new  data better fit for multiple peaks.

Comment: its a new thing for me thanks for that but still the program is not running. I have updated the program plz check..

Comment: you changed your script from using your original definition of `gaussian` to using the one from `lmfit.lineshapes`.  The two versions of `gaussian()` have different names for the function arguments and therefore different parameter names (`amp` becomes `amplitude`, `cen` -> `center`, and `wid` -> `sigma`).     You should really edit your question only update and clarify the question, not to change it entirely.  If you have a different question, ask a different question.   Or use the lmfit mailing list or better forum than SO for questions about the behavior of lmfit.

Comment: i m sorry actually i m new at this forum . i am still learning how to ask question here

Comment: just tell me how am i going to run this program  .. still getting error that "guassian" is not defined .. i removed from lmfit.lineshapes import gaussian.

Comment: Re: "just tell me how am I going to run this program",  Nope, that is not how StackOverflow works.  We're here trying to answer good, well-formed questions about programming that will be able to help others in the future.  We cannot do your homework, check your spelling (hint), or explain how Python `import` work in every question.  You keep changing your question: it was originally about not getting a good fit, then changed to be about how to fit multiple peaks, and has now devolved into rather basic questions about how to use Python.   Do not use comments to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: I GUESS M STUCK. THANKS

Comment: Well, if you *want* to be stuck, then you can be stuck.  If do not want to be stuck, you can ask a different question, or read up on what the error messages your getting, or use other forums as mentioned above. But StackOverflow is not an a free-form support forum for any problem you may have.